# Using .filter and .some to search nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 1 level nested object.

e.g. Teacher and Students. query hold the value entered in search bar. I am trying to filter the array but it does not seem to work. I am missing something basic but cant figure

```
const studentunderT = [
  {
    id: 1,
    therapist_FName: 'Wonder',
    therapist_LName: 'Women',
    students: [
      { id: 1, student_LName: 'Test', student_Initial: 'BT1' },
      { id: 2, student_LName: 'Test', student_Initial: 'AL' },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
{
        studentunderT.filter(post => {
          if (query === '') {
            return post;
        } else if (post.students.some(std=>(
            std.student_Initial.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())))) 
        {
          return post;
        }
        }).map((thr) => (
        <>
        {thr.students.map((stu) => (
            <Avatar color="red" key={thr.id} component={Link} to="/complete">{stu.student_Initial}
            </Avatar>
        ))
        }
```

Comment: What happens with your code currently?

Comment: It does not filter as I type the input....I expect to see only BT1 if I type B. After typing 3 characters the list vanishes.

Comment: But why do you have `return post` in your conditions, the `filter` method should have a callback which returns a Boolean `true` or `false` for each element which serves as the filter to be or not to be included in the final filtered array.

Comment: Since I see data with _firstname / lastname_ fields, I think you should read this article... [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: The logic should rather be first `.map`ping over all of the `studentUnderT` `if (query===''` and then `else` `filter` each element that `.includes(query)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, the callback passed to [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) must return a Boolean value (`true` to keep, `false` to discard). Yours potentially returns an object or `undefined`.

Sounds like you want something like this...

```ts
const queryResults = useMemo(() => {
  if (query.trim().length === 0) {
    return studentunderT;
  }
  const normalisedQuery = query.trim().toLowerCase();
  return studentunderT.filter(({ students }) =>
    students.some(({ student_Initial }) =>
      student_Initial.toLowerCase().includes(normalisedQuery)
    )
  );
}, [studentunderT, query]);
```

then you can use the memo-ised, filtered array in your JSX

```tsx
{queryResults.flatMap(({ students }) =>
  students.map((stu) => (
    <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">
      {stu.student_Initial}
    </Avatar>
  ))
)}
```

Note I've used the student `id` as the `key` for your `Avatar` component; the teacher ID would not have been unique for each student.

[image: Edit thirsty-hooks-h7e9ps]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter all the students separately, you can first create a flattened array with `Array#flatMap` before applying the filter.

```
studentunderT.flatMap(x => x.students)
    .filter(s => s.student_Initial.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
    .map(s => {/* return your JSX for each student */})
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the same as what OP's code indicates. This will return all the matching students but OP seems to want all the teachers who have students matching the query. They then show all of the students for those teachers

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to declare a variable of `filteredStudents` with a dynamic value and then inside your JSX just map over this filtered-students array.

NOTE: I used value `'B'` for `query` as you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871905/using-filter-and-some-to-search-nested-object/75872078#comment133829565_75871905).

```js
const query = 'B';
const studentunderT = [
  {
    id: 1,
    therapist_FName: 'Wonder',
    therapist_LName: 'Women',
    students: [
      { id: 1, student_LName: 'Test', student_Initial: 'BT1' },
      { id: 2, student_LName: 'Test', student_Initial: 'AL' },
    ],
  },
];
const filteredStudents = studentunderT.map(therapist => {
    if (query === '') {
     return therapist.students;
    }
    else {
     return therapist.students.filter(std => std.student_Initial
      .toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
    }
})
console.log('filteredStudents[0]:',filteredStudents[0]);
```

And then in your JSX:

```
filteredStudents[0].map(stu => (
 <Avatar color="red" key={stu.id} component={Link} to="/complete">{stu.student_Initial}
 </Avatar>
)
```

---

EDIT2:
As in the discussion bellow in the comments, if you were to have a more complex functionality, such as choosing between *therapists*, you can do that functionality such as that the `[0]` value to be dynamic rather than hardcoded:

```js
filteredStudents[therapistID-1].map(stu => ( //...
```

NOTE: `therapistID` would be a state that equals to = *therapist*'s `id`, you then subtract `-1` when accessing it, since arrays are 0-based meaning that they start at index `0` and I suspect you to use incrementing `id`'s of each therapist.

Comment: Why `[0]`? Won't OP want to show all the matching records?

Comment: @Phil its a nested loop, so both the conditions inside my `.map` either returns an **array** of *all students* if `query===''` or a `filter`ed **array** which `.map` pushes them *as if they are a single element* inside an array. So accessing `[0]` is still accessing all the students if the search `query` is empty.

Comment: I think the sample data is just an example. I expect there to be more than one top-level element

Comment: I see that, I could overcomplicate things as well by trying to guess what the OP wanted. The logic I used to provide a solution is from the OP's information (*or the lack of it*) provided so far.